# How can I tweak Merge Sort so it can merge arrays up to n divisions?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

In merge sort algorithm, we divide the array we want to sort until it has 1 or 2 elements (as far as I know) and only then we start merging them. Is it possible to divide the array n times before it reaches the atomic level and start the merge from there?

E.g.: I have an array of 8 elements and I want merge sort to split it in 2 arrays of 4 elements and immediately start the merging process, without making any more divisions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, this is possible: you'll have to cover for all possibilities of how those 4 elements are ordered. Or you sort them with another sorting method.

Comment: Why not use bottom up merge sort, which skips the recursive splitting and starts off by treating an array of n elements as n sorted runs of size 1 and starts merging immediately. Note that almost all libraries implement a stable sort as a hybrid insertion sort to create small sorted runs, followed by bottom up merge sort, such as [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). Top down merge sort is mostly an academic exercise.

Comment: @rcgldr, that's a nice strategy. However, I'm doing exactly what you said: an academic exercise, and my teacher asked me to use the top down merge sort strategy. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You can use a similar strategy with top down merge sort: once the number of elements is <= K (K = 16 or 32), switch to insertion sort. This will save about 10% of the run time.

Comment: Whereas you *could* do that, I'm kind of curious as to why you'd want to complicate the algorithm. The recursive algorithm is very elegant. I see no particular benefit to making the modification that you suggest.